# Calculating the number of holidays between a date range in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, holidays-gem

how to exclude holidays from total days ?

how to get the number of public holidays as per US calender ?

```
<script>
    function labourcostcalc() {
        var date1 = $('#CostMaster_labour_allocationdate').val();
        var date2 = $('#CostMaster_labour_deallocationdate').val();
        var diff;
        if (date1 >= date2) {
            diff = new Date(Date.parse(date1) - Date.parse(date2));
        } else if (date1 < date2) {
            diff = new Date(Date.parse(date2) - Date.parse(date1));
        }
        alert('Diff  date ' + diff);
        var days = diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
        alert(days);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to store this holidays somewhere or query a public service that provides that information for you. You can save a list of dates in your database and query (count) than by range using ajax

```
$.get('/yourservice/getdates',{begin: date1, end: date2}, function(holidaysCount) {
   days -= holidaysCount;
});
```

In your server you will need to create a table and a query like this

```
select count(1) from holidays where holiday_date between :date1 and :date2
```

Comment: example or sample code plz

Comment: I've updated the answer and you need to be more specific on what are you doing and which language your server runs....